# Downloading old version of qgis to Windows

Tags: qgis-2, download

I have bought the book "Learning QGIS 2.0" by Anita Graser and wish to work through the tutorials therein in order to improve my knowledge of QGIS.  I currently use QGIS 1.8 and wish to download version 2.0, as I think I would get confused if I were to download the latest (2.6?) version.  What's the easiest way to get hold of version 2.0?

Answer (score 4):

To download older version of QGIS, follow [this link](http://qgis.org/downloads/). Version 2.0 is [there](http://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.0.1-3-Setup-x86.exe). You'd better use the latest version to get use to it !

Comment: This is the official locations for all qgis versions